# An example of a space that does not satisfies the 1º countability axiom

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let be $X=\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ endowed with the product topology and $M=\{1_A: A\subset \mathbb{R} ~~\text{is a finite set}\}.$  How to show that:

1. $1_{\mathbb{R}}\in \overline{M}$
2. There is no sequence $\{1_{A_n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $1_{A_n}\to 1_{\mathbb{R}}$

Comment: I can answer the first item, in fact any onpen $O\ni 1_{\mathbb{R}}$ have the form $O=X\times\cdots X\times U_{i_1}\times X\cdots X\times U_{i_n}\times X\cdots$ so if we put $A=\{i_1, \ldots, i_n\}$ we have that $1_A\in O$ then as $O$ is arbitrary   follow it $1_{\mathbb{R}}\in \overline{M}$

Comment: in the above coment $X$ must be changed by $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(1_{A_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be any sequence in $M$ and take $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$.

Then $U:=\pi_x^{-1}((1/2,3/2))$ is an open set in $X$ such that $1_{\mathbb{R}}\in U$ but for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $1_{A_n}\notin U$, where $\pi_x:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is the $x-$th projection.